# Use RunAsInvoker .bat use for additional installations within initial wizard

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, runas

I have been using the `.bat` file with the typical `cmd /min /C "set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start "" %1"`  line of code to bypass the admin password window which has been working well in all cases.

However, in this case I run into a peculiar problem where 1. I open the install wizard using the aforementioned `.bat`, and 2. the wizard asks me for additional installations, which causes the admin password window to pop up (see below):
[image]

Obviously when I click that Install button I get the admin window to pop up again, however contrary to other cases I am unable to bypass that using the `.bat` file; there is simply nothing to drag and drop into the `.bat` file.

What I have tried doing is installing the two requirements one by one manualy using the `.bat` file which I have managed to do, however the wizard still comes up with the same window seemingly not recognising what I have already installed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the RunAsInvoker compatibility mode can only prevent the elevation prompt; it does not grant the process the actual administrative privileges. Therefore, if the child process requires administrative access to perform certain operations, it may still encounter access denied errors or fail to function as intended. Also, remember that  one may still encounter with unable to write/access denied errors on protected folders like 'Program Files'.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading 7zip and then drag the installer in the 7Zip logo. Then extract the file where you would usually want to it be installed at. Sometimes it works. I think it works with winRAR but I am not sure.